# How Do I Allow Unique Permissions and Anonymous Access?

Tags: anonymous-authentication, inheritance

I have a situation in Sharepoint where we have departments with different folders, we want everyone to have access to these folders to read but only each department head to have write access to their department's folder and documents in that folder.  From what I have gathered, once you break inheritance of permissions from the parent, it disables anonymous access.  Is there any possible way around this "feature"?